# Finding text between 2 strings

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to get something between 2 strings in HTML email source code i am using c#. The part of html is:

```
<td width="200" align="right" valign="top" style="line-height:22px; font-size:20px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color:#636363; text-decoration:none;">

9/7/2018

</td>
```

i need the date 9/7/2018.i have tried the regex,

```
color:#636363; text-decoration:none;">(.*?)</td>
```

This should Capture string between `color:#636363; text-decoration:none;">` and `</td>`. but its not working. i think newline and blank characters are causing problems.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use xpath selector for that?

Comment: [You can't parse \[X\]HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/107625)!

Comment: Try `color:#636363; text-decoration:none;">([\s\S]*?)</td>` to get rid of new line issues

Comment: Use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://html-agility-pack.net/).  You cannot parse HTML with Regex

Comment: @RubensFarias  this seems to work but there is " causing the pattern error https://imgur.com/a/jCScNpF

Comment: You can make `.` match newlines with `RegexOptions.Singleline` - [`(?s)color:#636363; text-decoration:none;">(.*?)</td>`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=color%3a%23636363%3b+text-decoration%3anone%3b%22%3e%28.*%3f%29%3c%2ftd%3e&i=rif%3b+color%3a%23636363%3b+text-decoration%3anone%3b%22%3e%0d%0a%0d%0a9%2f7%2f2018%0d%0a%0d%0a%3c%2ftd%3e&o=s), but you should parse HTML with a dedicated parser.

Comment: Here is also old way coding   `var lPos = myString.IndexOf("</td>", 0);
  int fPos = 0;
  if (lPos > -1)
   fPos = myString.LastIndexOf('>', lPos);
  
  var result = myString.Substring(fPos + 1, lPos - 1 - fPos);
   Console.WriteLine(result.Trim());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so you want this?
You did not escape the / in `</td>` and you needed to add in the new line characters.
This should do you nicely

```
color:#636363; text-decoration:none;\">[\r\n]+(.*?)[\r\n]+<\/td>
```

Comment: its just part of code there are other dates in code too. i need this specific date

Comment: @RanaJawad I have updated my answer for you then.

Comment: Take a look at this https://imgur.com/a/mYeXTWA

Comment: @RanaJawad Simple fix, just escape it. Updated.https://regex101.com/r/tsdJVa/2/

Comment: this worked just perfect                                                                                                    color:#636363; text-decoration:none;\">[\r\n]+(.*?)[\r\n]+</td>

Answer (score -1):

Try below pattern

```
<td[^>]*>(.*?)</td>
```

It will ignore all attributes.

Comment: its not usable because there are other td tags too and it is capturing whole text from <td to </td>.  tested on regex101

Comment: I think this is what you have mentioned in your question. Its better if you can share your full html and then specify which part you want to get.

Comment: @ArunKumar it does not matter, Regex is not what you should be using for HTML parsing.  Dont encourage it

Comment: @maccettura Totally agree. Better option is to go for HtmlAgilityPack.